# Highcharts not displaying chart from csv file

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have only a single series of data that I want shown on a column chart. A number for the days of the week.

data.csv
`1,6,7,3,6,15,9`

I want to display as a bar chart:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.get('data.csv', function (csv) { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Daily Usage'
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Hours'
            }
        },
        labels: {
            items: [{
                style: {
                    left: '50px',
                    top: '18px',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Day',
            data: {
                csv: csv
            }
        }, {
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Average',
            data: [1, 16, 3, 6.33, 10, 3, 5],
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                fillColor: 'white'
            }
        }
        ]
    });
});

});
```

The graph doesn't render. It's blank. The title is there though.

Comment: You need to parse your string values into numbers. Visit [this](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module) website to see how you can do it.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I don't see anywhere on that page saying strings must be parsed to numbers. If you're referring to just the website, then yes, I looked there first before posting but didn't see that part. Maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the csv values in an array and parse the values using JSON.
Example,

```
        series: [{
           name: 'Day',
           data: JSON.parse("[" + s1 + "]")  // s1 contains the csv values
        ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

in general CSV holds values separated by commas, these values will be in string format.

While Highcharts accept data to be present as comma separated array of numbers.

please check if they are strings or numbers and parse the values to numbers if required.

Hope this will help you to solve the issue.